# Build array from specific indices in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I filter out the index of zero which contains the name of the rows being returned from a MySQL query, and then put the results back into a array like the one shown below.

Desired example array:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:10 [
    0 => array:2 [
      0 => "2016-01-06"
      1 => 10
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      0 => "2016-01-12"
      1 => 15
    ]
  ]
]
```

Array that's returned from MySQL query:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:10 [
    0 => array:2 [
      0 => "price_1"
      1 => 10
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      0 => "day_1"
      1 => "2016-01-06"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      0 => "price_2"
      1 => 15
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
      0 => "day_2"
      1 => "2016-01-12"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like (assuming `$array` is your input array with the MySQL results, and `$output` is our transformed result array):

```
<?php

$output = array_map(function($value) {
    return [$value[1][1], $value[0][1]];
}, $array);
```

Here's an example using your input:

```
php > var_dump($array);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "price_1"
      [1]=>
      int(10)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "day_1"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2016-01-06"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "price_2"
      [1]=>
      int(15)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "day_2"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2016-01-12"
    }
  }
}
php > $output = array_map(function($value) { return [$value[1][1], $value[0][1]]; }, $array);
php > var_dump($output);                                                        array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2016-01-06"
    [1]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
php >
```